# Adding dropdown in redoc create using properties file

Tags: java, swagger, markdown, dropdown, redoc

In swagger redoc I have created external table using markdown, Now I need to create my own dropdown using markdown. Can you please help me out, that I can implement the same.

Comment: What kind of dropdown - a simple combobox (HTML `select`) or something else?

Comment: yes simple combo box with 2 values. On selecting value show their respective table.
I have done through collapsible. But cannot do with combo box.